# Descargar Nasdaq dataframe tick

Tags: python

Quiero saber si alguien sabe o tiene los valores de los últimos tiempos de nasdaq, los dataframe en valor de tick, si alguien sabe donde los puedo encontrar o descargar o conseguir que me responda porfavor.